# How do I align the tick marks to the chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

[image: This is the chart I am referring to in my question below]

In this chart I have created, there is space between the tixk marks on the x axis and the x axis/chart. How can I put the tick marks closer to the x axis so that they align?

[image: Here is an example of tick marks that align to the x axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you could supply your code and sample data, but try adding `coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` per my made-up example 2. Per example 1, I'm wondering if the zero line is not actually your x axis.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = rep(1:5, 2), y = 0:9) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
tibble(x = rep(1:5, 2), y = 0:9) |> 
ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue! The 0 was not on my x-axis